Adaptation of the interface when the on-screen keyboard is switched on
When you activate the input\textarea, the height changes, so that certain elements are no longer available, and others overlap. I'm using react js, is there any way to adapt the interface when the keyboard is enabled?
I tried to solve the problem myself via useRef, but I encountered two problems

After closing the keyboard, the input\textarea was still active and the elements were inactive
Scrolling to the desired element did not work correctly and I had to make several clicks, not automatically

UPD: I found a solution to this problem
For those who are looking for a solution:
const scrollToElement = (elementId) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (element && window.visualViewport) {
        const scrollHandler = () => {
            element.scrollIntoView({block: "start", inline: "nearest", behavior: "smooth"});
            window.visualViewport.removeEventListener('resize', scrollHandler);
        };

        window.visualViewport.addEventListener('resize', scrollHandler);

        setTimeout(() => {
            window.visualViewport.removeEventListener('resize', scrollHandler);
            element.scrollIntoView({block: "start", inline: "nearest", behavior: "smooth"});
        }, 1000);
    } else if (element) {
        element.scrollIntoView({block: "start", inline: "nearest", behavior: "smooth"});
    }
}; 

This function (if possible) uses the virtual keyboard API and performs automatic scrolling, to run it, you need to input\textarea
<textarea id="" onFocus={() => {scrollToElement('element's id')}}/>

